# Getting content from DIV in another page

Tags: javascript, html, button

Ok... 
Now: i'm on a page, and i have this button on my bookmark...

```
<a href='javascript:var n=document.getElementById("get_nuno").textContent;window.open("http://pgcc.datasource.pt/simples.php?vals="+encodeURIComponent(n), "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=100,height=100");'
   onclick="return false;"
style="text-decoration:none"
>
```

It loads the  from my current location...

what i want to do, is something like this...

```
[anotherpage].getElementbyId('get_nuno').textcontent
```

And then let the code be the same..,

Comment: Dp you really mean Java and not JavaScript?

Comment: Could you explain better your problem, maybe rewriting the question?

Comment: yes, JS... ok, i have one button in my bookmarks.

Comment: It will pop up a windows, and i want that windows to have values from a page

Comment: But not from the page where i am, from another one :) btw, i clicked on enter, thinking that it was a paragraph xD

Comment: are you working with any server side framework? showing us your code will help a bit, but you have to edit your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: @nunong21 where is this other page? Is it a page from another site or is it your own page? is the content within the div on that page static or is it user entered?

Comment: @kidmnot they are @ the same server, but from different domains, i want to get the div content (by id) and show it on pgcc.datasource.pt

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but it seems what you are looking for is AJAX. jQuery has an awesome `load()` function that would allow you to load specific elements from another page (eg `$.load('yourdomain.com/pathtofile#desiredelementID')`). Note that AJAX generally does not work if the URL you are calling to has a different domain (cross domain requests).